# ¿Porque cuando ejecuto una instrucción de curl sin el comando sudo se ejecuta correctamente pero si lo hago sin sudo se queda cargando?

Tags: python, linux, bash

Estoy tratando de corregir un error de un proyecto que llevo realizando en los últimos 6-7 meses. Mi ámbito se enfoca a la ciberseguridad y mi herramienta esta escrita principalmente en python y en algo de bash. Esta herramienta funciona con [ngrok](https://ngrok.com), y mi error se presenta cuando se ejecuta lo siguiente:

Primero que nada se ejecuta ngrok de la siguiente manera;

```
./ngrok tcp 443 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Y posteriormente se ejecuta la siguiente instrucción:

```
curl -s -N http://127.0.0.1:4040/status | grep "tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:[0-9]*" -oh > ngrok.tcp
```

De tal forma que el enlace TCP generado se guarde en el archivo ngrok.tcp, mi herramienta afuerza debe de ejecutarse con sudo para que funcione correctamente, pero cuando la ejecuto con sudo la instrucción de curl se queda cargando y no me muestra el enlace TCP en el archivo ngrok.tcp, aparte en el archivo ngrok.tcp despues de que se ejecuta la instrucción de curl me muestra "file is unwritable" al momento en el que lo abro con nano, pero todo esto no pasa si yo ejecuto mi herramienta sin sudo, y eso es lo que no he podido solucionar, por favor si alguien sabe como solucionar esto hagamelo saber se los agradeceré mucho, saludos.

Comment: buenas, aquí hay dos preguntas diferentes: una sobre permisos y otra sobre curl. La de permisos habría que escribirla bien detallada, indicando claramente cómo creas cada archivo y la línea exacta donde usas `sudo`. Lo suyo sería que después cambies la propiedad del archivo. En cuanto a la pregunta sobre curl, necesitaríamos un [mcve] para que podamos replicar el error. Es decir, la clave aquí es focalizarnos en los problemas (la parte de tu script es interesante pero irrelevante probablemente)

Comment: Lo que si se es que este problema no es debido a mi script, el error no se encuentra en la parte de mi código, porque al ejecutar manualmente esas 2 instrucciones de ngrok y curl con sudo no me genera el enlace, pero si lo pongo sin sudo si lo hace, al igual si alojo esas instrucciones en un archivo.sh y lo ejecuto con sudo no me deja, en si el problema no es con curl pero de igual forma lo especifiqué, el problema es con el "sudo"

Comment: Habría que ver exactamente por qué `curl` se congela. Hay quien sugiere hacer `curl ... | sudo grep` pero si todo el script se ejecuta con sudo esto no ayuda. ¿Te pasa lo mismo si haces curl a webs externas? Básicamente para poder validar nosotros qué puede estar pasando, pues tu web 127... como es normal nosotros no la podemos probar